# Non-linear function that provides an average value of 3 between two bounds

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have the following question:

*Find a non-linear function $z = f(x, y)$ such that the average value of $z$ is 3 for $-1 \le x \le 5$ and $-4 \le y \le 4$.*

My first thought was the following:

$$ \frac{1}{[(5)-(-1)][(4)-(-4)]} \iint_{R} f(x, y) dA = 3 $$
$$ = \frac{1}{48} \iint_{R} f(x, y) dA = 3 $$
$$ = \iint_{R} f(x, y) dA = 144 $$

Then, break up the integral into x- and y-components:

$$ = \int_{x = -1}^5 \int_{y = -4}^4 f(x, y) dy dx = 144 $$

Then, if $ \int_{y = -4}^4 f(x, y) dy $ was equal to $24$, $ \int_{x = -1}^5 \int_{y = -4}^4 f(x, y) dy dx $ would be equal to $ 24x \Big|_{-1}^5 = 144 $.

However, I have no idea how I would create a non-linear function $f(x, y)$ such that $ \int_{y = -4}^4 f(x, y) dy $ would be equal to $24$. Am I even on the right track?

Thank you.

Comment: The next simplest function to a linear function is a quadratic function. Choose a simple quadratic in $x,y$, find its mean, and scale it down. That should be fairly easy. (In fact, you could argue that the constant function equal to $3$ is not a linear function.)

Comment: Step functions are not linear and easy to integrate. I recommend looking for one of those.